# Need a live UDP echo Server IP and port

Tags: testing, udp, echo

I require to test my UDP program using echo server. I have tested this application in LAN but now I require it to test it in Internet.

Is there and globally recognize freely available well known ECHO server that I can use directly in my application ?

Please help, thanks....

**EDIT**
I already have a java based Echo Server program which I run on my desktop and connect the mobile using Wifi. Now I want tho check the app for Internet so I need the IP an port of some live server much like the  DayTime service, provided by some IPs.

Comment: I was looking for one of these recently, and found none. I think the minimum way of doing it involves getting your own server (eg from Amazon)

Comment: I was looking for UDP public server that will report me back my source port. I found http://www.tcpbin.org/ but apparently they are down or my NAT is more restrictive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most unixes (and linuxes) [have one built into](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echo_Protocol) xinetd, the "Internet Superserver".
Shove these lines in `/etc/xinetd.conf` and restart the service

```
echo   stream  tcp     nowait  root    internal
echo   dgram   udp     wait    root    internal
```

Answer (score 1):

Rahul,

If you can install python and the Twisted module I highly recommend running this simple script to create your UDP echo server.

http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/examples/echoserv_udp.py

Google Python Twisted for more information or hit me back here.

I hope this helps,

dc

Comment: Why? When there's a builtin one?

Comment: Life is all about choices and this one works for Windows, Linux, and MAC.

Comment: Nitpick - "MAC" is Media Access Control, or maybe something else. It's capitalized because it's an acronym. "Mac" is a shortening of Macintosh. It's not capitalized because it's not an acronym.

Comment: I would hope the with context clues the user would be able to extrapolate that in this case MAC == Macintosh. But thanks..

Comment: Assume nothing.  Especially when dealing with users.

Comment: dc5553 - I didn't think anyone would think you were referring to anything else. It was a nitpick, because I was trying to make you look better in the future by using the proper terminology :-) It's like still talking about PDCs in active directory. Unless you're talking about the PDCe FSMO role, there's no such thing and someone mis-using the term looks less professional.